# Babel Transforms not compiling Scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am attempting to use babel to transform client side ES6 scripts to ES5, and write that to a file.

However my current setup just spits out the same code that it took in.

Code example below.

```
const babel = require('babel-core');

babel.transform(scripts, {}, (err, result) => {
  fs.writeFileSync(
    '/scripts/app.main.js',
    result.code, 'utf8'
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Babel 6.x does not ship with any transformations enabled. You need to
>   explicitly tell it what transformations to run. The simplest way to do
>   this is by using a preset, such as the ES2015 Preset.

So you need to use ES6->ES5 preset for example:

```
npm install babel-preset-es2015
```

Check https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/